# batch file command line start in same folder as executable on network path

Tags: batch-file, networking, path, cmd

I know from a desktop I can have a bat file that runs an executable with specific parameters and starts in the same path on the network where the executable exists, but how can I accomplish the same thing when calling the bat file assuming is in same folder as executable from another application?

For example:
\My-Network\app\PR8.exe /noload

I want to start specifically in \My-Network\app (same folder where PR8.exe exists) but not where it defaults to which seems to be c:\windows somehow.  I can't seem to do a cd on a UNC path and I don't want to use any path letters as the application also detects as to which server it is executing from as well.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to set a UNC working directory for Windows batch files without network mapping drives. However, in Windows 2000 and later, you can use the `PUSHD` and `POPD` commands to change the working directory to a UNC share when running your script.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file#Setting_a_UNC_working_directory_from_a_shortcut) gives us the example of creating a shortcut to your batch file where the `Target` is set to the following:

```
%COMSPEC% /E:ON /C "PUSHD """\\My-Network\app\""" & C:\PATH\TO\BATCHFILE.BAT & POPD"
```

In this case the Working directory attribute of the shortcut is ignored, as the `PUSHD` and `POPD` commands will change it to the path specified.

Comment: Thanks, turned out I also needed to add the following c# logic in my program when referencing relative files:  System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath